# I don't know why my app doesn't show ads?

Tags: reactjs, admob, apk, react-native

I created an app, I added react-native-admob and linked it
I changed /node_modules/react-native-admob/android/build.gradle file:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'

to

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'

and then build the apk with "./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease", but when I install the app in my phone it doesn't show ads.
This is my code

```
 import {
    AdMobBanner,
    AdMobInterstitial,
    PublisherBanner,
    AdMobRewarded,
  } from 'react-native-admob';
```

....

```
<View>
<AdMobBanner
    adSize="fullBanner"
    adUnitID="ca-app-pub-2174326550695558/6129769558"
     onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.error(error)}
 />
 </View>
```

Here is my AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.brawlcalculator">

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please share your AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file:

Add you admob application id to a meta tag inside your application tag

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
> // Look at this ... after the closing tag
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-2174326550695558~2753605675"
  />
</application>
```

Comment: which is the folder?

Comment: android > app > src > main

Comment: If I use the command "react-native run-android" with an emulator the ads shows, but when I build the apk they doesn't show. Could be a problem with device test id?

Comment: you have to add you applicationId to your androidManifest file << Because they updated their terms of use andnow it's mandatory>> ... second make sure the adUnit you're having is not a **test unit** when you build an apk for production

Comment: How can I add my applicationId?

Comment: Sign up first https://admob.google.com/ ... Second: create an app in your account ... Third: The app you added in your account should have an applicationId that will be in the form: `ca-app-pub-888887819995813~9777648798` .... Fourth: add that applicationId into a meta tag like the example I posted in my answer

Comment: I tried adding the code that you send to me(changing the value with my application id), but It gives me an error. Do I have to delete some lines first to copy your code or change something in your code?

Comment: The meta-tag has to be inside your application tag `<application>` ... and yes you should replace the value with your own ... and if it gave you any error, plz share it

Comment: Now It created the apk, I'm trying to install it

Comment: Try to remove the installed app on your emulator first ++ make sure you installed the latest version of react-native-admob `npm install --save react-native-admob@next` +++ if you're not using test unit ids ... and you <just> created it, you need to wait for a while until you could use it in your app

Comment: I created my admob account 1 month ago with the app and the ad units, so I'm sure I doesn't have to wait. I used the same ad ID for more adbanners. Now I have just 2 banners with 2 different IDs, but when I use "react-native run-android" it gives me and error :"the ad request was successful but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory"